lgpio: 'can not open gpiochip' lgpio seems unable to open gpiochip devices
I'm trying to run a GPIO program on my rpi5 using gpiozero, but I am unable to because of the error:
Unable to load any default pin factory!
and the warning above is:
Falling back from lgpio: 'can not open gpiochip'
I'm not sure why this error is occurring.
I'm running the script inside of a venv which may be changing the permissions and thus lgpio can't access /dev/gpiochip*/, but I'm not sure.
/dev/gpio[1-4] are all there, lgpio just doesn't seem to be able to reach them.

Your question is confusing. On the latest kernel /dev/gpiochip{1-4} DO NOT exist.

You have not specified HOW you setup venv.

The error isn't due to the venv or permissions. It's due to a change in the latest kernel release mentioned below in the accepted answer.

I am not disputing this; there is obviously a gpiozero error and it is attempting RPi.GPIO.  Your question confuses the issue by mentioning venv - there is no reason for venv and you would get a similar error if incorrectly setup and erroneous statements like  "/dev/gpio[1-4] are all there"

This may be related to a recent RPi kernel change.  The main GPIO block has changed from gpiochip4 to gpiochip0.  I'd guess that some software is still trying to use gpiochip4.
See
https://github.com/gpiozero/gpiozero/issues/1166
https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=376287

This is probably what the issue is from as I just wiped and redownloaded my sd card and did not perform any updates and the issue is cleared up. Redownloading Bookworm 64bit and not installing any updates was the solution that worked for me, but the solution in the first link of changing the default chip from 4 to 0 in lgpio.py may also work.

What a farce! Just confirmed (with gpioinfo) that GPIO has moved to gpiochip0 in Kernel
6.6.47+rpt-rpi-2712 . This SHOULD have been predictable and done before release (and really users should NOT have to worry about this detail). Also release with a deprecated libgpiod is inexcusable. Raspberry Pi Ltd. seem to be a bunch of amateurs; no planning. I will have to fix my kludge for Pi5 to handle different kernel releases.

Even though the firmware is dated 2024/07/30 there does NOT seem to have been any announcement.

@Milliways: Have you tried pinctrl??  :))

@Seamus your point is? I use pinctrl in my gpioreadall BUT I also note the notice that it is intended as a debug tool.
